# can not use special prinicipal 'sa'

Tags: sql-server-2008

On initializing the SQL server database of **OpenGTS** using command
**bin\initdb.bat "-rootUser:sa" "-rootPass:saPassword"** , I got an error an error
*"can not use special prinicipal 'sa'"*. How can I solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mixed Mode authentication, sa is disabled by default.

You can explicitly enable the sa account... check out the instructions [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/aa617c93-cd97-41ea-acbd-6345d4f8b890/cannot-use-the-special-principal-sa).